# Unable to produce wanted output, loops and arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops

Why on lord's green earth does my code not work? Was expecting an output of 5 prompts but instead the program gets stuck after the first or second scanf.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n[5], i, plus = 0, minus = 0;

    printf("Enter 5 positive/negative numbers: ");

    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", n[i]);

        if (n[i] > 0)
        {
            plus++;
        }
        else if (n[i] < 0)
        {
            minus++;
        }
    }

    printf("Total positive numbers: %d", plus);
    printf("Total negative numbers: %d", minus);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten that array indexes are *zero based*. I.e. an array of five elements have indexes from `0` to `4` (inclusive).

Comment: And `scanf("%d", n[i])` --> `scanf("%d", &n[i])`

Comment: Both the problem I pointed out, and the problem you're asking about, could be solved by reading just about any beginners book or tutorial.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No need to be this harsh, most questions on this site could be solved by reading a book too.
Anyway regarding the question, in C parameters by default are passed by value. This means that if we have a function like this `void f(int a)` then each time it's called the function will receive just a copy of `a`, not the real variable. Say, we have `int a = 5;` statement in `main()`. If we call `f(a);` and that functions somehow changes its value like `a = 10;` or anything similar to that, after the `f(a);` finishes the one `a` in the main will still hold the value of `5`...

Comment: ...To solve that problem, there's another way of passing parameters in C, which is by reference. To do that, just pass a pointer to the function, `void f(int *a);`. Now what we're actually doing is, we're passing the address or the location of the variable `a`. So now instead of passing a copy of the value, we're just telling the compiler where exactly to find that variable. And conversely to the previous method, if we change the value of `a` in the new `f(&a);` function, `a` will remain like that indefinitely (or until we change it ourselves or `main()` ends)...

Comment: In short passing the location of the variable allows the function to actually edit that specific variable, which is essentially what `scanf()` does. If you're not familiar with pointers yet, `int *a;` means that we declare essentially a number which can (but doesn't just yet) contain the location of an `int` of our choice. Said location (or address) is a positive hexadecimal number. If we state 
`int num = 5;`
`a = &num;`
the last line means that `a` now holds the location of `num`. The operand `&` returns the address of the variable it's put before...

Comment: ...So when you're passing a pointer to a variable in some function, use `&`. Just keep in mind that the name of the array without `[]`is already a pointer, which means that you shouldn't pass it using `&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry but `scanf` does not work that way. To write the value the user types in at the prompt, as `n[i]`, `scanf` needs *an address* (in memory).

C is in this regard intentionally rudimentary, more so than a language like Python or JavaScript.

The way you wrote your code, you end up passing garbage (whatever integer value is contained at the address `n + i`) as an argument to `scanf` and expect the machine to replace that garbage with the value. And it cannot do that.

An apt analogy would be if I asked you to take whatever you find by the door and put it on a shelf, but instead of telling you which shelf to put it on, I'd give you the object that is currently on the shelf. You'd be right to ask me "why did you give me this, and which shelf do I put that what I find by the door on?".

When you specify a variable as an argument to a procedure, what is passed is the *value* contained in the space allocated for the variable, commonly called the "variable value", of course.

You need to give `scanf` the *address of the space* to write to. The address of `n[i]` is obtained using the unary operator `&`, e.g. `&n[i]` or `n + i`.

Comment: _C is a portable assembler_: this statement is not correct at all.

Comment: The statement was intended to drive the point home -- one needs to understand memory addressing with C. Perhaps it is ill fit to state in general, what with optimizations a modern compiler puts into the translation and C99 and all. Anyway, if that's the only thing wrong with my answer, I can live with that :)